# Keep Background Image centered when resizing browser window

Tags: css, browser, background, resize, center

So I am making layout for an SMF forum and the background image is centered perfectly when the browser window is wide enough. However when I start shrinking the browser window, the background image starts moving to the left. Here is my current CSS for the background:

```
body
{
    background: #fefff1 url(../images/img/bg.gif) no-repeat;
    background-position:top center;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    color: #7C3C4A;
    padding: 0px 5%;
    font: 78%/130% "Verdana", "Arial", "Helvetica", sans-serif;
}
```

Here's a screenshot of the forums so that you can visualize it better:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uz3yT.png

Answer (score 6):

```
body
{
    background-color: #fefff1;
    background-image: url(../images/img/bg.gif);
    background-position: center center; /* First value is from left and second is from top. You can use use number as well*/
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}​
```

Comment: Not exactly what I had in mind. I've added a screenshot in the first post for reference.

Comment: Would you give me the actual link so I can take a look. Basically background images are not suppose to shrink.

Comment: You will need to login to see it. Username = testaccount | Password = 123456

Comment: The issue is not background image. You need to set your body's padding to 0. right now its 5% from the side. The padding pushes your body to the right and you think the background image is shrinking.

Answer (score 3):

Your code seems about right.

Only thing I did was consolidate background-position into the same background attribute up top like so:

```
body {
    background: #fefff1 url(../images/img/bg.gif) no-repeat top center;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    color: #7C3C4A;
    padding: 0px 5%;
    font: 78%/130% "Verdana", "Arial", "Helvetica", sans-serif;
}
```

Here's a JFiddle of it - [JFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/t4ACk/)

Comment: Ooh okay. However the problem is still there.